# Android map v2 change some names

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been wondering, is there any way I could change the name of (let's say a street name) on the     `google maps api v2`

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not! Why do you even want to do that?

Comment: You mean like a custom name of your own or change the whole Google thing?

Comment: No I need to change some street names (or add ones) so I can achieve what I want

Comment: You will have to contact Google in that case, OpenStreetMap provides such functionality but not Google.